# why the code using :eq("+e+")?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav ul li").each(function(e){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            $(".subnav .left div:not(:eq("+e+"))").hide();
            $(".subnav .left div").eq(e).show();
        })
    })
})
```

what's `div:not(:eq("+e+"))")`meaning in the above code? i don't know why it use two `+` in the parenthesis? could i use `div:not(:eq(e))")` to instead of it? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `+` is used to add two things together.

In this case, it's adding strings.

This:

```
".subnav .left div:not(:eq("+e+"))"
```

Means adding three strings to become one:

1. `.subnav .left div:not(:eq(`
2. `e`
3. `))`

The final result is the value of `e` added to the jQuery selector, `e` being the index of the currently iterated element.

The outcome of this whole thing in simple words is: when mouse is over specific list item, hide all `<div>` elements under `.subnav .left` except the `<div>` in same index as the hovered list item.

**Edit**: You can avoid the messy code and dump the `+` by having such code instead:

```
$(".subnav .left div").not(function(index) {
    return (index === e);
}).hide();
```

More lines, but also more elegant as you show the logic inside a function, not a string.

Comment: if i change it to this $(".subnav .left div:not(:eq(e))"),what's the result maybe?

Comment: @down321 That won't work because `e` will be passed as literal string and won't be recognized. you will get error actually, as `.eq()` expects a number.

Comment: @down321 see my edit, I think that is what you were looking for?

Comment: in the above code, :eq("+e+"), the argument in :eq() must be e,it's not the argument which passed from function(e). am i right?

Comment: @down321 not sure what you ask, but the updated code is doing the same thing without using `:eq()` so there should be no such problem anymore.

Comment: i understand your code it's more easy to understand , but still don't know the original code why not use :eq(e), what's the difference of :eq() and .eq()

Comment: With `:eq()` the value is passed as literal string. With `.eq()` the value is passed as function argument.

Comment: BTW, could i change :eq("+e+") to :eq("+index+") or other characters? thank you

Comment: @down321 of course you can change but then it would be meaningless because the index variable is called `e` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really stand messy code, so here's an alternative that (should) do the same thing:

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav ul li').mouseover(function(){
    $('.subnav .left div').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
  });
});
```